# Why is the mutiplication table for generators in the $su(3)$ algebra so bizarre?

Tags: group-theory, conventions, lie-algebra, strong-force

The square of the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ has the bizarre value $2/3 * I + \lambda_8 / \sqrt{3}$.

Is there a simple way to deduce the result from the fact that $\lambda_8$ is orthogonal to all other $\lambda_n$, and has trace $0$? (And maybe some other property.)

And a similar question: why is $\lambda_3^2 + \lambda_8^2 =4/3 * I$?
(This is related to the equally mysterious $\lambda_8^2=2/3 * I  - \lambda_8 / \sqrt{3}$.)

Is there a way to deduce these relations without using the specific representation matrices, by showing that the relations are valid generally?

Following the comments, I gather that the bizarre numerical values are due to historical choices of normalisations. But
is there a simple way to prove that both $\lambda_8^2$ and $\lambda_3^2$ must be linear combinations of the identity and of $\lambda_8$?

Comment: How much of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#The_SU(3)_group) is mysterious?

Comment: Hypercharge commutes with isospin, whose quadratic Casimir you got wrong?

Comment: Hi @KlausK: So you are asking about choice of convention?

Comment: @Qmechanic No, just the opposite: can one show these relations independently of conventions, independently of the matrix representation?

Comment: $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2-\sqrt{3}\lambda_8=2 I$ predicated on the Gell-Mann--Nishijima formula, and a uniform normalization for the orthogonal, hermitian, complete set of matrices as he constructed them. Fix your hypercharge value. It is only strange in the physics sense.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, are you saying that some expression in the question is wrong? I do not find any error...

Comment: The idiosyncratic definition of G-M's basis and its normalizations is predicated on the Gell-Mann--Nishijima formula, $ Q=\lambda_3/2+\lambda_8/2\sqrt{3}$; there is nothing basis independent about them. Are you asking how to write these in the Cartan-Weyl basis?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos How does the multiplication table look in the Cartan-Weyl basis?

Comment: I sent you [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Standard_basis) already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard normalization of Gell-Mann matrices (in the fundamental, triplet, of su(3)) is
$$
\operatorname{Tr} (\lambda_a\lambda_b) = 2\delta_{ab},
$$
and all 8 matrices are traceless, i.e. orthogonal to the 3-identity.

But note squares of generators are not in the Lie algebra, but in the universal enveloping algebra, and their properties vary with representation! Further note the "miracle"
$$
\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma_3^2=1\!\!1_2
$$
is *strictly* a feature of isospin in the doublet, and so 1/3 the value of the respective su(2) Casimir invariant, embedded in the same subspace of su(3). Check this fails for the triplet representation of isospin (in the octet of su(3))!

You are then *only* talking about *diagonal* matrices
$\lambda_3, \lambda_3^2, \lambda_8, \lambda_8^2, 1\!\!1_3$,
(where $\lambda_1^2=\lambda_2^2~(=\lambda_3^2)$ come along for the ride and need not be discussed). You are discussing
three mutually orthogonal 3-vectors, $V(\lambda_3),V(\lambda_8), 1\!\!1$  and fussing their normalizations following from above:
$$
V(\lambda_3)\cdot V( 1\!\!1)=0,\\
V(\lambda_8)\cdot V( 1\!\!1)=0,\\
V(\lambda_8)\cdot V(\lambda_3)=0 \\
V(\lambda_3^2)\cdot V(\lambda_3)=0,\\
V(\lambda_8)\cdot V(\lambda_3^2)=0 \\
V(\lambda_8^2)\cdot V(\lambda_8^2)=2 \\
V(\lambda_3^2)\cdot V(\lambda_3^2)=2 .
$$

It is thus necessary that the two vectors $V(\lambda_3^2)= (1,1,0)^T$ and $V(\lambda_8^2)=(1,1,4)^T/3$  be expressible as linear combinations of the fundamental three such above,
actually two, being orthogonal to $V(\lambda_3)$,
$$
V(\lambda_3^2) ={2\over 3} 1\!\! 1 +{1\over \sqrt{3} }\lambda_8, \\ 
V(\lambda_8^2) = {2\over 3} 1\!\! 1 -{1\over \sqrt{3}} \lambda_8,
$$
as you confirmed. The 2/3 coefficient of the identity is to align its trace/normalization, 3, with that of the λ matrices. I'm not sure why this should be bizarre.